# On link click new image with text appears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a page where when a link is clicked the corresponding image appears with a clickable link below it that will say "Click to view Gallery"

So far I have the code written to change the image using an 'onclick' command, but I am unsure how to add the text below the image.

Here is [my website](http://new.oxrealty.com/wp/index.php/commercial-properties/office/) with the current code now.

JS:

```
function changeImage(element) {
document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = element;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE001');">1025 W 3rd</a>
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE002');">959 - 965 Schrock Rd</a>
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE003');">7099 Huntley Rd</a>
```

[image]

So the text that reads ***Click to view Gallery of Property*** is what I need to be added beneath the image. That link needs to be a unique link that leads to the corresponding property based on the 'onclick' link that the user selects in the left column.

So for example, the user selects **1025 W 3rd** in the left column and it's corrisponding image shows up with an option for the user to view a gallery of that property alone (which will be a separate web page)

I am not sure what my next steps should be. Is it better to change the links to and 'onclick change div' type of command?

Thank you so much for your help.

-Kas

***EDIT***
I added my current code so any reader can better understand what I currently have.

Comment: Teemu, what would you call the code I have on my website then, so that I may better name the question?

Comment: I'd call the code on your website "*mostly irrelevant to the problem at hand,*" and "*liable to be changed profoundly when your problem is solved, making this question entirely useless to visitors in future.*" Also, the lack of the relevant ("[MCVE]") code in your question makes this question entirely off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please, [edit] your question in order to provide a useful question and to (hopefully) prevent your question being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a link bellow your image and add it an id.

```
<div id="divright">
    <img src="http://new.oxrealty.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/CommercialPropertiesDef.png" alt="Images" id="imageReplace">
    <a href="#" id="linkReplace">Click to view Gallery</a>
</div>
```

Then change your function `changeImage` to accept an additional argument for a link, and it should also change the href attribute of the link.

```
function changeImage(image, link) {
    document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = image;
    document.getElementById('linkReplace').href = link;
}
```

Then you change the links to call the updated function with the link

```
onclick="changeImage('CUSTOM_IMAGE', 'CUSTOM_LINK');"
```

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjsavjz3/)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need! Is there a way to make the link unique for each property? So for example, the user selects 1025 W 3rd in the left column and it's corresponding image shows up with an option for the user to view a gallery of that property alone (which will be a unique web page)?

Comment: @Kasandra Yes, you need to call the function with the link for the second argument. Check my edit.

Comment: it looks like the '#/' is in the side link, is preventing the gallery link from loading. Currently I do not want the page to jump to the top after the user clicks on the property name, this is why I have the '/' in there. Is there a way to solve this conflict?

Comment: @Kasandra you could remove `href="#"` from the `a element` or you  can add `return false;` to the `onclick` attribute like so `onclick="changeImage('CUSTOM_IMAGE', 'CUSTOM_LINK'); return false"`

Comment: There was one small problem I noticed. The default "Click to view Galler of This Property" has no link connected to it and only works if someone clicks on the property links for it to load the corresponding link. Is there a way to make this portion not visible until the user does so?

Comment: @Kasandra You should look at how to hide it with CSS and change CSS properties with Javascript. Then, if you are still having problems, it would be best, if you make another stack overflow question.

Comment: will do! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're fine with your code as you are. To change the value of a div with an id of "text" for example, you would just do in your JS:

```
document.getElementById('text').value = 'Type the new value here';
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Whoops! Just spotted it.

Comment: Can I have a unique gallery link corresponding with each image? So for example:

`<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE001');">IMAGE LINK 1</a>
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE002');">IMAGE LINK 2</a>
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE003');">IMAGE LINK 3</a>

<img src="http://new.oxrealty.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/CommercialPropertiesDef.png" alt="Images" id="imageReplace"/>

(And then each individual image has a unique link that leads to a unique page)

</div>`

Comment: Sure you just do it like this: `<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE001', 'The value of the div here');">IMAGE LINK 1</a>`. Not sure where the function is in your JS, but from there you can use the command I suggested in my answer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: So my current javascript looks like this:  `function changeImage(element) {
document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = element;

document.getElementById('text').value = 'Test Value Here 002';
}
`
Yet the value is not showing up under the image.

Comment: Two issues. Firstly it should be `function changeImage(element, text)` as your function is being passed two parameters. Also is 'text' actually the id of the div under the image, I just gave it as an example.